# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Sub: 'str' and 'int' on line 3

Tags: python

never mind, I found my mistake

I keep getting this error? TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Sub: 'str' and 'int' on line 3

this program is suppose to output overtime hours.

```
def computepay(hrs,r):
  if hrs > 40:
     hrs = hrs-40
     hrs = hrs *1.5
     hrs = hrs + 40
     pay = hrs*r
     return pay


hrs = raw_input ("Enter Hours:")

r = float (raw_input ("Enter monies:"))

p =computepay(hrs, r)

print p
```

Comment: Well, what are your thoughts about it? How could such an error happens? What does the traceback tell you?

Comment: This means your `hrs` in line 3 is string type.

Comment: never mind, I seen my error

Answer (score 0):

You get the input as a string. That is the problem here.

```
hrs = raw_input()
```

Here `hrs` is a string. If you want an integer, use:

```
hrs = input()
```

Or convert it to an int like you convert the `r` variable.

```
hrs = int(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your input to a float:

```
hrs = float(raw_input("Enter Hours:"))
```